# Filter wp_redirect() to stop redirect under certain condition

Tags: filters, redirect, wp-redirect

I am developing a tool to print PHP debug messages on screen.

I would like to stop the `wp_redirect()` function from actually doing the redirect if the debug tool contains a message that it wants to display.

One way would be to check this before calling `wp_redirect()` at all, but it's preferable to have something like a `before_redirect` filter where I can decide to "go on" or "don't go".

I have seen the [`wp_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_redirect/) filter allows me to filter the redirect location.

I could say "go back to the same place" but that would be a new http request and the logs would be already lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the source code, [`wp_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) always ends in a PHP [header](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) request, **except** if the location is empty, because then it doesn't know where to redirect. So you can indeed use the `wp_redirect` filter. If you return an empty string under certain circumstances, the redirect will not happen.